# Efficiently return words that match, or whose synonym(s), match a keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database of industry-specific terms, each of which may have zero or more synonyms.  Users of the system can search for terms by keyword and the results should include any term that contains the keyword or that has at least one synonym that contains the keyword.  The result should then include the term and ONLY ONE of the matching synonyms.

Here's the setup... I have a `term` table with 2 fields: `id` and `term`.  I also have a `synonym` table with 3 fields: `id`, `termId`, and `synonym`.  So there would data like:

```
term Table
id | term
-- | -----
1  | dog
2  | cat
3  | bird

synonym Table
id | termId | synonym
-- | ------ | --------
1  | 1      | canine
2  | 1      | man's best friend
3  | 2      | feline
```

A keyword search for (the letter) "i" should return the following as a result:

```
id | term   | synonym
-- | ------ | --------
1  | dog    | canine     <- because of the "i" in "canine"
2  | cat    | feline     <- because of the "i" in "feline"
3  | bird   |            <- because of the "i" in "bird"
```

Notice how, even though both "dog" synonyms contain the letter "i", only one was returned in the result (doesn't matter which one).

Because I need to return all matches from the `term` table regardless of whether or not there's a synonym and I need no more than 1 matching synonym, I'm using an `OUTER APPLY` as follows:

```
<!-- language: sql -->

SELECT
    term.id,
    term.term,
    synonyms.synonym
FROM
    term
    OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT
                TOP 1
                term.id,
                synonym.synonym
            FROM
                synonym
            WHERE
                term.id = synonym.termId
                AND synonym.synonym LIKE @keyword
        ) AS synonyms
WHERE
    term.term LIKE @keyword
    OR synonyms.synonym LIKE @keyword
```

There are indexes on `term.term`, `synonym.termId` and `synonym.synonym`.  `@Keyword` is always something like `'%foo%'`.  The problem is that, with close to 50,000 terms (not that much for databases, I know, but...), the performance is horrible.  Any thoughts on how this can be done more efficiently?

Just a note, one thing I had thought to try was flattening the synonyms into a comma-delimited list in the `term` table so that I could get around the `OUTER APPLY`.  Unfortunately though, that list can easily exceed 900 characters which would then prevent SQL Server from adding an index to that column.  So that's a no-go.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "flattening the synonyms into a comma-delimited list in the term table: - Have you considered using Full Text Search feature? It would be much faster even when your data goes on becoming bulky. 
You can put all synonyms (as comma delimited) in "synonym" column and put full text index on the same.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you.  I still have to manually pick just one of the many synonyms that are returned but there was a 10+-fold improvement in speed here.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad that it helped... You can try this -                                           
SELECT id, term, left([synonym], CHARINDEX(',',[synonym]))
FROM [dbo].[TableName] a WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE([dbo].[TableName], [FTSColumnName], @keyword) t
ON t.[key] = a.Id                                                                                
Please note that you will have to put "," or whichever separator you are using after synonym even if there is a single synonym e.g. Feline,

Comment: Thanks again.  I had already implemented the pick one thing in code but just gave your suggestion a try.  I'm finding that, for my needs, the code version works better but I appreciate the suggestion.  Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of unnecessary logic in there. There's no telling how SQL server is creating an execution path. It's simpler and more efficient to split this up into two separate db calls and then merge them in your code:

Get matches based on synonyms:

```
SELECT
 term.id
,term.term
,synonyms.synonym
FROM
 term
 INNER JOIN synonyms ON term.termId = synonyms.termId
WHERE
 synonyms.synonym LIKE @keyword
```

Get matches based on terms:

```
SELECT
 term.id
,term.term
FROM
 term
WHERE
 term.term LIKE @keyword
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I need to also return the matching synonym in case the keyword matches the synonym but not it's associated term.  I'm not sure how I would do that, while using `DISTINCT` since a single term could have multiple, matching synonyms.

Comment: Ok, in that case you might be better off splitting this up into two separate db calls. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get results also with the synonyms of the words, I recommend you to use Freetext. This is an example:

```
SELECT Title, Text, * FROM [dbo].[Post] where freetext(Title, 'phone')
```

The previous query will match the words with ‘phone’ by it’s meaning, not the exact word. It will also compare the inflectional forms of the words. In this case it will return any title that has ‘mobile’, ‘telephone’, ‘smartphone’, etc.

Take a look at [this article](https://csharpvault.com/blog/sql-server-full-text-search/) about **SQL Server Full Text Search**, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @Arnel.  I think that this capability of Full Text Search, in general, would absolutely be helpful.  I neglected to mention in my original post though that the synonyms I'm dealing with here are highly industry-specific and are derived from an official source.  Given that, freetext would not be a viable solution for my specific needs but certainly would be in most other scenarios.